# Why can't I stack two readers ontop of eachother?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I get errors like this:

Let's say I have a monadStack `ReaderT A (ReaderT B m)`, whenever I use `ask` or `asks`, I get an error like this:

```
Types.hs:21:10:
    Couldn't match type ‘A’ with ‘B’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘MonadReader B m’
        arising from the instance declaration
      instance ‘MonadReader A m2’ at Types.hs:21:10-63
    In the instance declaration for ‘MonadReader A m’
```

How come Haskell can't figure out which instance to use? Also, how can I solve this?
Let's say putting `A` and `B` in the same datatype is not an option, because I need a `MonadReader A m` instance.

Comment: Oh, `instance (MonadReader r m) => MonadReader r (ReaderT s m)` doesn't even exist?! Why is that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `MonadReader` class is defined using the `FunctionalDependencies` extension, which allows declarations like

```
class Monad m => MonadReader r m | m -> r where
    ...
```

This means that for any monad `m`, the `r` is uniquely determined by it.  Therefore, you can't have a single monad `m` that determines two different `r` types.  Without this as a restriction the compiler wouldn't be able to type check uses of the class.

The solution to this is to write your functions like

```
getA'sInt :: A -> Int
getA'sInt = undefined

getB'sString :: B -> String
getB'sString = undefined

foo :: (MonadReader A m) => m Int
foo = do
    a <- asks getA'sInt
    return $ a + 1

bar :: (MonadReader B m) => m String
bar = do
    b <- asks getB'sString
    return $ map toUpper b
```

Then just use a tuple `(A, B)` in your actual implementation:

```
baz :: Reader (A, B) (Int, String)
baz = do
    a <- withReader fst foo
    b <- withReader snd bar
    return (a, b)
```

There's also a `withReaderT` for more complex cases.

As an example for why it's not allowed to stack `ReaderT`s, consider the case

```
type App = ReaderT Int (Reader Int)
```

When you call `ask`, which `Int` are you referring to?  It may seem obvious that for cases like

```
type App = ReaderT A (Reader B)
```

the compiler should be able to figure out which to use, but the problem is that the `ask` function here would have the type

```
ask :: App ???
```

Where `???` could be `A` or `B`.  You can get around this another way, by not using `MonadReader` directly and defining specific `askA` and `askB` functions:

```
type App = ReaderT A (Reader B)

askA :: App A
askA = ask

askB :: App B
askB = lift ask

baz :: App (Int, String)
baz = do
    a <- askA
    b <- askB
    return (getA'sInt a, getB'sString b)
```

But you will only be able to have `MonadReader A App`, you can't also have `MonadReader B App`.  This approach could be called "explicit lifting", and it makes those functions specific to the `App` type, and therefore less composable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for that last comment, how do you chose which one of `MonadReader A App` or `MonadReader B App` you get, because that would in fact solve my problem.

Comment: @SydKerckhove Whichever one's on top.

Comment: @SydKerckhove So if you had `ReaderT B (Reader A)` then you'd have the `MonadReader B` instance.

Answer (score 7):

It can be done using some extensions, though it might not be a good idea to have overlapping instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader

import Data.Functor.Identity

data A = A deriving Show
data B = B deriving Show

type SomeMonad a = ReaderT A (ReaderT B Identity) a

instance MonadReader a m => MonadReader a (ReaderT b m) where
  ask = lift ask
  local f mx = do
    b <- ask
    lift $ local f $ runReaderT mx b

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let res = runIdentity $ flip runReaderT B $ flip runReaderT A $ do
              a <- ask :: SomeMonad A
              b <- ask :: SomeMonad B
              return (a, b)
  print res
```

Needless to say, whenever possible it's much better to use something like `ReaderT (A, B) IO`.

Comment: This is what I had just figured out, and it works! I just hoped for a clearer (safer) solution.